# OpenCV 3.0 OpenCL UMat addition error

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl, gpgpu, opencv3.0

I am trying to use OpenCV (3.0 beta) transparant API for OpenCL but I have weird compilation errors for simple operations (at least for addition and subtraction).

Here is an example code :

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/ocl.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat temp;

int main() {

    // activating opencl
    ocl::setUseOpenCL(true);

    UMat mat1 = UMat::ones(3,4,CV_32F);
    UMat mat2 = UMat::ones(3,4,CV_32F);
    UMat mat3;
    mat3 = mat1 + mat2;
    mat3.copyTo(temp);
    cout << "mat3 = " << endl << " " << temp << endl << endl;
}
```

I am getting that error :

```
/home/matthieu/git/stages/singapore/opencv_perf_tests/opencl_test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/matthieu/git/stages/singapore/opencv_perf_tests/opencl_test.cpp:19:17: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘cv::UMat’ and ‘cv::UMat’)
    mat3 = mat1 + mat2;
                ^
```

This is the same with subtraction.
I can't find anyone with the same kind of error. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: there are no overloaded maths operators for UMat. you will have to use add(), subtract(), etc.

Comment: Thanks @berak , I can compile now but the performances does not change at all.

Comment: I used that code :

    UMat mat1 = UMat::ones(3000,400,CV_32F);
    UMat mat2 = UMat::eye(3000,400,CV_32F);
    UMat mat3;
    add(mat1, mat2, mat3);
    subtract(mat1, mat2, mat3);
    gemm(mat1,mat2,1.0,noArray(),0.0,mat3,GEMM_1_T);

Perfs are exactly the same. I am a beginner, does someone know a simple tutorial for beginners for OpenCL in OpenCV 3.0 ?

Comment: Have a look at that maybe : [learnopencv](http://www.learnopencv.com/) :)

Comment: Great resource @KtorZ but already went there ;) I think my problem is more related with drivers but not sure.

Comment: When you changed it, did it work ?

Comment: @TripleS using add, substract, etc instead of operators did work (I mean no more compiling error and the results were ok) but I did not manage to make it work on GPU (it was using CPU) and never tried later.

Comment: I'm experience a similar problem, I'm trying to run Umat code on Intel HD graphics, currently CPU is better than opencl intel graphics